# Unable to get subtab upon clicking tab by using new android support Material design TabLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

My requirement is to put Main Tabs on the screen with default selected subtabs and its associated display. On clicking of 
any main tab, it should replace existing subtab & its associated display. I am currently working in Material desin Tablayout.

Here is my code for displaying main tabs

```
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    TabLayout maintabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintabs);
    maintabLayout.addTab(maintabLayout.newTab().setText("Product"));
    maintabLayout.addTab(maintabLayout.newTab().setText("Store"));
    maintabLayout.addTab(maintabLayout.newTab().setText("Company"));
    maintabLayout.addTab(maintabLayout.newTab().setText("Service"));
    maintabLayout.addTab(maintabLayout.newTab().setText("User"));
```

which works well

The code for replacing subtab & its associated display is as follows (this is not working and hence need suggestion)

```
          maintabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new       
        TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            int numTab = tab.getPosition();
            switch (numTab) {
                case 0://Product
                    ViewPager pviewPager = (ViewPager)            

                    findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                    String[] pname = {"ProCat1","ProCat2","ProCat3"};
                    pviewPager.setAdapter(new  
                    FragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                            MainActivity.this));
                    return;
                case 1://Store
        ViewPager sviewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                    String[] pname = {"Store1","Store2","Store3"};
                    sviewPager.setAdapter(new 
                  FragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                            MainActivity.this));

                    return;
                case 2://Company
        ViewPager cviewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                    String[] pname = {"Comp1","Comp2","Comp3"};
                    cviewPager.setAdapter(new 
               FragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                            MainActivity.this));

                    return;
                case 3://Service
        ViewPager serviewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                    String[] pname = {"Serv1","Serv2","Serv3"};
                    serviewPager.setAdapter(new 
                 FragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                            MainActivity.this));

                    return;
                case 4://User
                    ViewPager uviewPager = (ViewPager)   
               findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                    String[] uname = {"Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3"};
           uviewPager.setAdapter(new 
          FragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                            MainActivity.this));
                    return;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```